# Confidence intervals of linear model with several factors

Tags: confidence-interval

I am trying to interpret the coefficients and confidence intervals of a model that has several categorical variables. I cannot share this model but I managed to narrow down my situation to a simple example.

Let's say that I want to model the weight of animals from three categorical features of the animals: cat/dog, house/wild and friendly/unfriendly. The following toy dataset creates such

```
> require(dplyr)
> set.seed(1234)
> toy = expand.grid(animal=c('cat', 'dog'), 
                    habitat=c('house', 'wild'), 
                    friend=c(T, F), 
                    observation=seq(100)) %>%
        mutate(weight=ifelse(animal=='cat', 15, 20) +  
                      ifelse(habitat=='house', 0, 5) + 
                      rnorm(n=nrow(.))) %>% 
        select(-observation)  # drop observation, not used
> head(toy, 8)

  animal habitat friend   weight
1    cat   house   TRUE 13.79293
2    dog   house   TRUE 20.27743
3    cat    wild   TRUE 21.08444
4    dog    wild   TRUE 22.65430
5    cat   house  FALSE 15.42912
6    dog   house  FALSE 20.50606
7    cat    wild  FALSE 19.42526
8    dog    wild  FALSE 24.45337
```

So I create a model `weight ~ animal + habitat + friend`. Since there are three categories, coding them as 2^3=8 columns would give a rank-deficient matrix, but `R` knows this and it creates the correct matrix design by grouping these binary factors. We can verify this with the `model.matrix` function:

```
> lm1 = lm(weight ~ animal + habitat + friend, data=toy)
> model.matrix(lm1) %>% head(8)
  (Intercept) animaldog habitatwild friendTRUE
1           1         0           0          1
2           1         1           0          1
3           1         0           1          1
4           1         1           1          1
5           1         0           0          0
6           1         1           0          0
7           1         0           1          0
8           1         1           1          0
```

And the model results:

```
> summary(lm1)

Call:
lm(formula = weight ~ animal + habitat + friend, data = toy)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3347 -0.6526 -0.0069  0.6284  3.2479 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 14.96788    0.07094 211.003   <2e-16 ***
animaldog    4.98014    0.07094  70.205   <2e-16 ***
habitatwild  4.99066    0.07094  70.354   <2e-16 ***
friendTRUE   0.03934    0.07094   0.555    0.579    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.003 on 796 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9254,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9252 
F-statistic:  3293 on 3 and 796 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So this makes sense to me, but the intercept *absorbs* all cases where the binary variables are zero. In other words, the intercepts represents the mean weight for unfriendly house cats. This is not really a problem, I just need to be careful when interpreting the model coefficients.

For example, unfriendly house cats weigh about 14.96, but if I want to know the weight of friendly wild dogs it would be 14.96 + 4.98 + 4.99 + 0.03 = 24.96.

---

Now, I turn to confidence intervals, I have them calculated with a bootstrap method, but here let's assume that they have the same results as `confint`:

```
> confint(lm1)
                  2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) 14.82863826 15.1071290
animaldog    4.84089540  5.1193861
habitatwild  4.85141476  5.1299055
friendTRUE  -0.09990898  0.1785817
```

**The question:**

What would be the confidence interval for the weight of friendly wild dogs?

Naturally, I thought that this could be estimated as the sum of all confidence intervals above. For unfriendly house dogs, it would be the confidence interval of `(Intercept)` + the interval of `animaldog`.

While this seems logic to me (it would be like the calculation of the coefficients in the first part), I am not entirely sure and it *feels* like I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

No, CI can not be manipulated in that way.

Method 1: Get the estimated covariance matrix of $\hat \beta$. (maybe the software will not give it to you by default, but you can force software by adding some options,...)

Use $Var(\sum \hat \beta_i)=\sum(Var(\hat \beta_i) + 2\sum_{i>j} Cov(\hat \beta_i,\hat \beta_j)$.

Get the CI by $\sum \hat \beta_i \pm Z \sqrt{$Var(\sum \hat \beta_i)}$.

Method 2: In you bootstrap stage, calculate the statistics that you need, such as "14.96 + 4.98 + 4.99 + 0.03 = 24.96", then get CI from them.

Comment: Interesting. Method 2 makes a lot of sense, but it would cost me some computation time. I could use Method 1 since I do have the covariance matrix of $\hat\beta$, but I wonder if this has some underlying normal assumption? Do you have a link/reference that one could read concerning this approach?

Comment: Method 1 is based on the assumption that $\hat\beta$ has multivariate normal distribution. If $\epsilon$ follows normal, of course $\hat\beta$ will be normal. But even $\epsilon$ not normal, $\hat\beta$ will be asymptotic normal if your sample size is large enough. From your results on se and CI on $\hat\beta$ it seems assuming $\hat\beta$ be normal is acceptable. I have no link/ref because this kind of thing is very old and common.