# Beta regression estimates and confidence intervals on response scale

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm, logit, beta-regression

I'm using GLMMadmb for my beta regression. I'm having a bit of trouble. I understand beta regression uses the logit link function and I know how to get from logits to probability. Here's selected output from the regression:

```
Call:
glmmadmb(formula = pctrans ~ tree + (1 | tree:trayid), data = BT.data, 
family = "beta")

AIC: -1149.8 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.16290    0.15136   -7.68  1.6e-14 ***
tree1       -0.01288    0.21310   -0.06     0.95    
tree2       -0.26647    0.21345   -1.25     0.21    
tree3       -0.03386    0.21318   -0.16     0.87    
tree4        0.00934    0.21285    0.04     0.96    
tree5        0.82941    0.21220    3.91  9.3e-05 ***
```

Converting the estimates for any variable, aside from the intercept, requires adding the intercept estimate to its own estimate before converting from logits to probability.

When I use confint() on the model, I get:

```
                 2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -1.4595573 -0.8662370
tree1       -0.4305435  0.4047932
tree2       -0.6848254  0.1518833
tree3       -0.4516802  0.3839700
tree4       -0.4078356  0.4265210
tree5        0.4135036  1.2453123
```

I'm assuming a similar procedure must be done here? e.g.,

```
exp(-1.459 + (-0.431)) / (1 + exp(-1.459 + (-0.431)))
```

After doing so, all of my confidence intervals are lopsided. Is that to be expected? Am I missing something critical?

Comment: You should be able to run `emmeans::emmeans(model, ~ tree, type = "response")` or something similar to get upper and lower bounds.

Comment: @MarkWhite
Thanks! That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Comment: @MarkWhite It seems that for beta and GLMM regression, emmeans uses asymptotic confidence intervals. Any thoughts on that? Obviously I'd rather have more accuracy, but I also think in this case the confidence intervals might not be critically important to the take home messages of my work. Also, how do I find $Cov(\hat \alpha, \hat \beta_1)$?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed as a_statistician said, assuming that there is a `vcov()` and a `coef()` method available for objects produced by `glmmadmb()`, you could do something like this:

```
X <- rbind(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0))
V <- vcov(fm)
logit <- c(X %*% coef(fm))
se_logit <- sqrt(diag(X %*% V %*% t(X)))

probs <- plogis(logit)
lower <- plogis(logit - 1.96 * se_logit)
upper <- plogis(logit + 1.96 * se_logit)
```

where `fm` is the name of your fitted model.

Answer (score 2):

No, CI can not be manipulated in that way.
See [Confidence intervals of linear model with several factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372372/confidence-intervals-of-linear-model-with-several-factors/372378#372378). I answered this very similar question today.

In your situation, let $X_i= $ tree$i$, your model is 
  $g(\mu) = \alpha + \sum_{i=1}^5\beta_iX_i$ 
To get the CI for $\mu|X_1=1$, need to get CI for $\alpha + \beta_1 $ first, which is $\hat \alpha +\hat\beta_1 \pm \sqrt{Var(\hat \alpha +\hat\beta_1)}$, where $Var(\hat \alpha +\hat\beta_1) = Var(\hat \alpha) +Var(\hat\beta_1)+2Cov(\hat \alpha, \hat\beta_1) = 0.15136^2 + 0.21310^2+2Cov(\hat \alpha, \hat\beta_1)$.

You did not provide $Cov(\hat \alpha, \hat\beta_1)$ in your question.

Then convert this CI into response acale by $\left\{\frac{exp(L)}{1+exp(L)}, \frac{exp(H)}{1+exp(H)}\right\}$

Comment: Why couldn't OP do `inv_logit <- function(x) exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)); lb <- inv_logit(-1.16290 - 0.4305435); ub <- inv_logit(-1.16290 + 0.4047932)` where `lb` is the lower bound and `ub` is the upper for  $y | X_1 = 1$? That is, always take the point estimate of the intercept and use the lower and upper bound for $\beta_1$ to increment or decrement it?

Comment: Let $z=f(x,y)$ be function of parameters $x,y$. You can use $\hat z = f(\hat x, \hat y)$ as the point estimate of $z$, although it is biased if $f$ is not linear. (but asymptotically unbiased). But for CI,  $z_l=f(x_l,y_l)$ and   $z_u=f(x_u,y_u)$ are wrong.

Comment: I create an example: Let $X\sim N(10,4)$ and $Y\sim N(10,4)$ and independent with each other. We have 95% of $X$ will be in (10-2*1.96, 10+2*1.96), smae as $Y$. Let $Z=X+Y$, can we use (20-4*1.96, 20+4*1.96) cover 95% of $Z$? We know that $Z\sim N(20,8)$, (20-1.96*$\sqrt 8$,   20+1.96*$\sqrt 8$) covers 95% of $Z$. Obviously, (20-4*1.96, 20+4*1.96) is too wide.

Comment: Yup, I did a little simulation and found this to be the case: https://gist.github.com/markhwhiteii/cb5635d75589dcbedc48859b2a1f3dd4

Comment: Actually, is this more due to `confint()` using the profile likelihood method for CIs instead of the typical `confint.default()` method that uses the standard 1.96 * the standard error?

Comment: @Mark Are you talking with me? I do not know how to use R. I am familiar with SAS. In SAS, use ESTIMATE statement, you can get these kind of estimate very easy.